# How to create a menu from get_nav_menu_locations when it always returns an empty array?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu

In the wordpress dashboard I've created a menu under appearance -> menus and named it "my-menu".

Using example code from [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_items) I'm trying to build the menu. In my `/wp-content/themes/blankslate/header.php` I add the following code:

```
$menu_name = 'my-menu';
$locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
print_r ($locations);
```

Basically on every page the `$locations` is an empty array even though I've created and saved the menu. Was hoping to create menus and having the name of it in a custom field so every page can have it's own menu (or nothing when left empty or default menu when custom field not provided).

Guess I'm not getting the way wordpress intends the user to use it, maybe it's just a checkbox somewhere. I did notice that when I check the box `Main Menu` under Appearance -> Menus the array returned isn't empty but `$locations[ $menu_name ]` is not set.

Using wordpress 3.6.1 with a modded blankslate theme.

**[UPDATE]**
The functions.php is hardly changed and the register_nav_menus is set with the following parameter:

```
array( 'main-menu' => __( 'Main Menu', 'blankslate' ) )
```

I guess that's where the `Main Menu` checkbox in Appearance -> Menus on the Dashboard comes from. Commenting out this line makes `Menus` disappear all together.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $locations = get_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations' );
print_r($locations);
```

try this

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the following code `$locations = get_theme_mod( 'nav_menu_locations' );var_dump ($locations);` results in: `array(1) { ["main-menu"]=> int(2) } ` What should I do with the number 2 or the string `main-menu`?

Comment: IT RETURNS an array with the registered navigation menu locations and the menu assigned to it, main-menu is your menu name slug you can use it

Comment: I've added a menu called `main` and set that to the main menu, now when I execute `$locations = get_nav_menu_locations();` the $locations has one item named `main-menu` it still didn't fetch the menu named `my-menu`. I guess before `my-menu` was called main-menu because it's the main menu. I would like to use the main menu only if a `menu-name` custom field hasn't been set. In this case I set the `menu-name` to `my-menu` and would like that menu to be loaded but `get_nav_menu_locations` returns only one item and that's the main menu (named main).

Comment: There is no function ref for get_nav_menu_locations so I'm not sure what it is supposed to do but I'd expect all the menus to return.

Comment: how did you set `main-menu` to `my-menu` ? you have to register first these locations  to use later

Comment: did you see this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_nav_menu ?

Comment: The checkbox Main Menu in the WP dashboard under Appearance -> Menu. Thank you for the link but it doesn't seem to explain what get_nav_menu_locations is supposed to do. WP uses it in the page mentioned in my question but the code doesn't do what I want it to do. Had a peek in `/wp-includes/nav-menu-template.php` and solved it using a function `wp_get_nav_menus` It's also undocumented (no function ref found on a quick google search) but it seems to be doing what I want to do. Added an answer and thank you for your help in this.

Answer (score 0):

In /wp-content/themes/blankslate/functions.php

```
function getDefaultMenu(){
  $loc=get_nav_menu_locations();
  $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object( $loc['main-menu'] );
  return $menu;
}

function getMenu() {
  global $post;
//set menuName to custom field called menu-name
  $menuName = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'menu-name', true);
//menu to use
  $useMenu = false;
//get available menus
  $menus = wp_get_nav_menus();
  //if no custom field was given use default-menu
  // will fail if no menu is set to default
  if (!$menuName) {
    $useMenu=getDefaultMenu();
    if(!$useMenu){
      throw new Exception("Please make one of the menus".
        " the main menu under Appearance => Menus");
    }
    return wp_get_nav_menu_items($useMenu->term_id);
  }
  //find the menu with the $menuName
  // either default-menu or the custom field called menu-name
  foreach ($menus as $menuItem) {
    var_dump ($menuItem);
    if ($menuItem->name === $menuName) {
      $useMenu = $menuItem;
      break;
    }
  }
  //if no menu was found raise an error
  //menu-name must be provided as a custom field
  // or default menu must be set
  if (!$useMenu) {
    throw new Exception("Can't open menu named:" . $menuName .
    " Make sure you set a custom field called menu-name" .
    " with the name of one of the menus under Appearance => Menus".
    " Or set one of the menus to Main Menu.");
  }
  return wp_get_nav_menu_items($useMenu->term_id);;
}
```

In /wp-content/themes/blankslate/page.php

```
$menu_items=getMenu();
var_dump($menu_items);
$menu_list = '<ul id="menuid">';
foreach ((array) $menu_items as $key => $menu_item) {
  $title = $menu_item->title;
  $url = $menu_item->url;
  $menu_list .= '<li><a href="' . $url . '">' . $title . '</a></li>';
}
$menu_list .= '</ul>';
```

Example code doesn't show how to handle nested items but I'll update when I figure that one out.